# Problema al crear un "Nuevo elemento con scaffold" en asp.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, controller, visual-studio-2017, ado.net

Buenas.

He estado siguiendo un tutorial desde "EF Database First with ASP.NET MVC"y me he quedado estancado en esta [parte](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/generating-views), necesito una ayuda, soy bastante nuevo en este tema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos.

Comment: Prueba a compilar toda la solución antes de añadir el controlador y las vistas. Un saludo

Comment: Intenta `Ctrl+B` y dinos que pasa

Comment: que tontería, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como menciono @Einer se debe compilar nuevamente la solución o presionar `Ctrl+B`.

Comment: Gracias por no dejar sin responder tu pregunta, y aceptar tu respuesta <3